# I can't understand how use(.) in sql statements

Tags: sql

> ```
> Student (student_id, student_name, year, GPA)
> Course (course_id, course_name, credits, dept_id )
> Enroll (student_id, course_id, mark, grade)
> ```

```
SELECT stu.student_name FROM Student AS stu, Enroll AS enr
WHERE stu.student_id = enr.student_id AND enr.course_id = "SCS1008" AND enr.mark < 80
ORDER BY stu.student_name;
```

There use Stu.Student_name.

I want to know from where  the stu has come and without any attribute as stu, how to use it.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: it is simply namespacing  - when joining two or more tables

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `enr.course_id = "SCS1008"`  is invalid standard SQL

Comment: Regrading Gordon's comment. Implicit vs explicit join can be seen here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an alias for the `Student` table, by virtue of `Student AS stu`. The alias `stu` allows you to reference the `Student` table by using a shortened name elsewhere in the query. It is short for `Student.Student_Name`, that being the `Student_Name` field on the `Student` table.

Comment: It is worth to mention, that aliases become a necessity when you have to join a table to itself. Aliases in this case allows you to distinguish between the two instances of the same table.